# Looping through column in dataframe with python TypeError: len() of unsized object

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, dataframe

Below is a for loop I am writing but it keeps returning an error. Cant quiet figure out how to fix the error. I think it has to do with the if statement but do not know what to fix.

TypeError: len() of unsized object

```
for i in df_py['Type']:
    if i == df_stroke['Type']:
        print True
    elif i != df_stroke['Type']:
        print False
```

My main objective is to to compare the two dataframes within their respective value in 'Type'. Each dataframe has similar values but I wish to loop through to automate the process. Comparing the two values then returning a true or false statement to tell me if they match.

```
print(type(df_py['Type'].values[0]))
print(type(df_stroke['Type'].values[0]))
```

Returns: 
type 'numpy.int64', type 'numpy.int64'

Both are the same type.

```
> 2     if i == df_stroke['Type']:
  3         print True
  4     elif i != df_stroke['Type']:
  5         print False
```

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.pyc in wrapper(self, other, axis)
    739             return NotImplemented

```
740         elif isinstance(other, (np.ndarray, pd.Index)):
```

--> 741             if len(self) != len(other):

```
742                 raise ValueError('Lengths must match to compare')

743             return self._constructor(na_op(self.values,np.asarray(other)),
```

TypeError: len() of unsized object

Comment: The error you show doesn't seem to originate from the code you shared...

Comment: And by the way you can do more concisely `print i == swim_df_stroke['Type']` instead of the unnecessary if block...

Comment: the error is from the loop.

Comment: ['Type'] is a column in the dataframe

Comment: where exactly? there is no usage of `len` in your code. You need to provide the full error message, including call stack, and exact line where the error fires...

Comment: the main issue is i dont think the for-loop is looping through the values within df_stroke['type].

Comment: sorry the error is so messy

Comment: put it and edit it in your post itself...

Comment: Error added to post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [`eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#flexible-comparisons).

```
# generate some example data.
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

N = 10
values = ['a','b','c']
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Type": np.random.choice(values, size=N)})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Type": np.random.choice(values, size=N)})
```

`eq` gives element-wise comparison:

```
df1.Type.eq(df2.Type)

0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
6    False
7    False
8    False
9     True
Name: Type, dtype: bool
```

Comment: You're welcome!  If this resolved your question, please mark it accepted by clicking the check mark to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The segment    `for i in df_py['Type']` iterates through `df_py['Type']` and assigns it to `i`. However, while comparing it, you compare one item of `df_py['Type']` which is `i` to the whole dataframe `df_stroke['Type']`.

You have not specified what exactly you are trying to achieve with your code, so my suggestion is to change `df_stroke['Type']` to `df_stroke['Type'][<some index>]` or use the various other dataframe operations to perform the comparisons.